# Sending emails from your alias in Office365?

Tags: office-365

Is there a way to send emails from an email alias in Office365? Currently alises only allow receiving emails to that alias which is not helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Not natively. There exists third-party tools/services tht allows office 365 user to send as alias.